# Create Direct2D1 bitmap and draw it to Direct2D1 RenderTarget

Tags: c#, bitmap, direct2d, sharpdx

I want to do the following without using WIC:

1. Create a Direct2D1 Bitmap and draw something into it.

   ```
   BitmapProperties props = new BitmapProperties(new SharpDX.Direct2D1.PixelFormat(Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm, AlphaMode.Premultiplied));
   var renderT = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.BitmapRenderTarget(m_d2dRenderTargetImage, CompatibleRenderTargetOptions.None, new SharpDX.Direct2D1.PixelFormat(Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm, AlphaMode.Premultiplied));

   renderT.BeginDraw();
   renderT.Clear(SharpDX.Color.Yellow);
   renderT.EndDraw();
   ```
2. Save this Bitmap to a variable.

   ```
   RastImage = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap(renderT, new Size2(targetWidth, targetHeight), props);
   ```
3. Draw this Bitmap into a Direct2D RenderTarget.

   ```
   m_d2dRenderTarget = new RenderTarget(m_d2dFactory, surface, rtp);
   ```

But this does not do anything. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Does it even work without WIC? Any help is welcome. I have searched a lot but never really found an example without WIC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, it was too easy to see.

```
RastImage = rendertT.Bitmap
```